# add a way to list questions with ignored tags concisely

Tags: feature-request, questions, ignored-tags

Currently, as I see, there are two modes of showing questions with ignored tags: dimmed out (the default) and hidden completely.  It would be useful to have another mode, whereby such questions would be listed, but very concisely, basically just one line for summary, probably also dimmed out.

The idea is to have something intermediate: dimmed out, but full-size entries still look too prominent, while with hidden entries you could miss an unexpectedly interesting question if it used tags too liberally.